# Reverse an input character string

Tags: c

I would like to reverse an input character string and I use the the pointer which points to the last character and make it print the string while the pointer address decreases. However, I could not get the whole string. Could anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
//Reverse a charater string
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char a[50];
  int l;
  int *p;
  printf("Please input a character string:\n");
  scanf("%s",a);
  l = strlen(a);
  for (p = &a[l-1]; p >= a; p--)
   {
     printf("%c",*p);
    }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}

Output:
Please input a character string:
asdfasdfasdf
fff
```

Comment: Do you mean [*reverse*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reverse)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the use of the `int` type for `*p`.

Since an `int` on your system is 32 bits wide (four times bigger than a `char` which is 8 bits on your system), when the pointer is being decremented, it is printing out every fourth character in the reverse of the string.

So, with your sample string, `asdfasdfasdf`, the pointer points to the last `f`, then the middle `f`, then the first `f`.

Similar example:

```
Please input a character string:
abcdefghijklmno
l is 15, a[l-1] is o
okgc
Press any key to continue . . .
```

If you change your pointer to the `char` type it will decrement properly, pointing to every character in the string in reverse order.

Answer (score 3):

You have declared `p` as integer pointer. It should be a char pointer.

```
int *p;
```

should be

```
char *p;
```

Comment: This is just one step though, no? I don't think just replacing that part will completely solve the problem. Still +1

Answer (score 1):

When you increment/decrement a pointer of type `T*`, the address contained in it changes by `sizeof(T)`. Since you have declared `p` to be `int*`, the pointer address changes by `sizeof(int)`. On your machine `sizeof(int) == 4*sizeof(char)`, explaining the result you see. Change the type of `p` to `char*`.