# Pointer with different type than the referenced variable

Tags: c, pointers, types

I am currently learning how to program in C. Today I started with pointers, and I encountered the following situation. When I compile the program

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a;
    double * p;
    p = &a;
    *p = 12.34;
    printf("%d\n",a);
    * (int *) p = 12.34;
    printf("%d\n",a);

    return 0;
}
```

it says

```
$ gcc zeigertypen.c 
zeigertypen.c: In function ‘main’:
zeigertypen.c:7:7: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

and upon execution, I get the output

```
2061584302
Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

The error message is German for something like

```
memory access error (core dumped)
```

However, if I comment out the line `*p = 12.34;` the error disappears and the output is

```
0
12
```

The purpose of the code is to demonstrate the problem with pointers of different type than the variable they are referencing. According to the textbook I'm using to learn C++, the output should be

```
2061584302
12
```

Comment: I'd get a new textbook, looks like it's telling you to include c headers and dictate the output of undefined behaviour.

Comment: It is actually C, not C++, I'm programing in @George. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Well either way I would look to the age and validity of the book, maybe it's lying to you and will move on to a section about [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), but if not, well... :/

Comment: You should put up the warning level of your compiler. For this code, it should shout at you.

Comment: The compiler warns you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse an input character string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24967171/reverse-an-input-character-string)

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Yes, my textbook also pays attention to that, but it suggests to try the code anyway.

Comment: @George: What is funny is that the book actually makes the largest part of a course in programming in C/C++. It's one of these courses where the material is sent to your home and then you are reading it and in the end you have to pass an online exam in order to get the certificate.

Comment: @StefanHamcke If it were me ( I am a little pretentious ) i'd point the error out to whoever your exam board is, it wouldn't be fair if you were dropped marks due to poor material. Anyway, hope you do well :)

Comment: @George: Thanks :) The online exercises are actually adapted quite closely to the material, so I assume that's the case for the online test as well, so maybe I have to learn wrong facts in order to pass the exam :-) But that's just one reason more to point out the errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour of `p = &a;` is actually *undefined*.

Neither C nor C++ allow you to re-interpret the type of `&a` (which is a pointer to `int`) as a pointer to a `double`.

`(int*)p` is similarly problematic, although by then the damage has been done.

You are allowed to cast to `void*`, and back to the original type from `void*`: for now, regard these as being the only cases where you can cast the type of a pointer to a different type.

Comment: So, because we defined `p` as a `double *` pointer, `p = &a` is undefined?

Comment: Absolutely. The compiler reserves the right to eat your cat if you write that. (What's most likely happening is that *p is trashing the memory after `a` which is your pointer `p`. A `double` is probably a larger type on your system than `int`).

Comment: I can actually avoid the error by using float instead of double. But then again, the textbook did not assume that double has the same size as int. So one could say, the book is still lying.

Comment: If the book implies that the cast will work if the sizeof the two types is identical then its only use is for kindling over the winter.

Answer (score 0):

Explaination with code: (Acc to your Textbook)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a;  // size let say (2 byte or 4 )
    double * p; // it will point to continous memory of 8 byte
    p = &a;     // Now because of this ,starting from first byte of a it will derefer 8 bytes (but Undefined behaviour acc to C standards)
    *p = 12.34;  // assigned to those 8 bytes
    printf("%d\n",a);  // first (2 or 4 ) bytes of that value in *p assignment as it starts from a
    * (int *) p = 12.34; // now you type casted it to derefer 2 bytes so store 12 in those (2 or 4) bytes as int
    printf("%d\n",a); // first (2 or 4) bytes of that value in *p assignment

    return 0;
}
```

if you need more explaination comment and ask me . Thank you.

Comment: It was ;) But it's not because I don't like you o.O I just don't think the explanation explains the op s output which is sort of what their question was. I'll revoke the dv because while I doubt this will help the op it might help others :)

Comment: Lemme help! as I like helping beginner after all I was a teacher for so long so I like to help it's just that @George

Comment: @Corey Lemme comment more specific is it okay? and where I went wrong can you explain me?

Comment: it does not follow standards but I think I just explained what's the book referring.